# Custom Reusable UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to make a custom table cell that handles filling of text fields automatically. My idea is that I'll just pass an object to the cell class and the cell will then automatically fill in the fields. Everything works fine except that no button inside the cell work, they are all unclickable. What am I doing wrong?

Main Screen:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
        Claim *claim = [statementsArray objectAtIndex:row];
        NSString * strIndentifier;

        strIndentifier = @"StatementDetailsCellIdentifier";

        StatementDetailsCell *cell = (StatementDetailsCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:strIndentifier];


        cell.hasWarranty = claim.hasWarranty;
        if(cell == nil) 
        {
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"StatementDetailsCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [statementCell initWithClaim:claim reuseIdentifier:strIndentifier];

            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;        
         }

           return cell;
    }
```

Cell.m :

```
    -(id)initWithClaim:(Claim *)_claim reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
    {
        self = [self initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
        claim = _claim;

        [self populate];
        return self;
    }

    -(void)populate 
    {
        barcodeLabel.text = claim.barcode;

        NSLog(@"claim is %@", [claim description]);

        if(claim.points == 0 || claim.points == 0.00)
            valueLabel.text = @"Pending";
        else
            valueLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"£%.2f", claim.points];

        modelLabel.text = claim.product;
        warrantyLabel.text = claim.warranty.name;
        APIRequest *apiRequest = [[APIRequest alloc] init];
        dateLabel.text = [apiRequest parseDate:claim.date];
        //hasWarranty = claim.hasWarranty;

        double timeS = [apiRequest getUnixTimestamp:claim.date];
        NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
        NSDate *trueDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeS];
        double timeDiffrece = [now timeIntervalSinceDate:trueDate];
        double threemonths = 90*24*3600;

        //Warranty Button

        if(claim.hasWarranty)
        {
            UIImage *buttonImage;
            //13-6-2013
            if([claim.warranty.name isEqualToString:@"Pending"])  {
                buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imgBtnWarrantyPending.png"];
                pendingHelp.hidden = NO;
            } else {
                pendingHelp.hidden = YES;
                buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"warranty_claimed.png"];
            }
            [warrantyButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [warrantyButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
            [warrantyButton removeTarget:nil action:NULL forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];
        } 
        else 
        {
            pendingHelp.hidden = YES;
            if(false) {
                [warrantyButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [warrantyButton removeTarget:nil action:NULL forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];
            } else {
                [warrantyButton setTag:claim.ID];
                UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"add_warranty.png"];
                [warrantyButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [warrantyButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
                [warrantyButton addTarget:self action:@selector(haha:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
                warrantyButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
                warrantyButton.enabled = YES;

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's this for?  `if(false) {`

Comment: That's just a temporary hack to bypass some of the intended logics.

Comment: Have you initialized warrantyButton, otherwise all the code will silently not work

Comment: I've build all the uilabels and uibuttons on IB..

Comment: Forgot to say that all the texts are showing. Only the button is not working. I tried addTarget:self action:@selector(aTrivialMethod:) and adds that trivial method that prints out stuff using NSLog, but it's not doing that

Comment: Try to change `UIControlEventTouchDown` to `UIControlEventAllTouchEvents`

Comment: what do you mean by unclickable, do you mean that it is deactivated or just not responding to the selector action ? put a break point in selector methos (haha) and check whether it is coming insdie that method or not.

Comment: Still not doing it. The buttons simply don't press (no highlighting). I created a simple round rect button, also not clickable.

Comment: @xman it's not pressable at all. As if it's a static image. The haha function is not called at all, tried breakpoints + NSLog

Comment: try this 
[warrantyButton setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];

Comment: I also tried attaching the file owner's function to the touchupinside event with IB. Also not working

Comment: tried userinteraction enabled, still not clicking

Comment: what other components are there in cell along with warrantyButton ?
Check whether any other UILabel frame or UIImage getting overlapped on this button,
in that case button wont respond as it is overlapped by other component.

Comment: tried moving the elements around as well, to no avail. I think it's a initialisation issue, since it worked when I used awakeFromNib to populate the fields. But I need to pass on the Claim object

Answer (score 0):

Might be your target would be remove from method . Please assign a break point at the strating of populate method and try to show or hide warrantyButton if target assign for check. and double check name of images.

```
   if(claim.hasWarranty)
    {
        UIImage *buttonImage;
        //13-6-2013
        if([claim.warranty.name isEqualToString:@"Pending"])  {
            buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imgBtnWarrantyPending.png"];
            pendingHelp.hidden = NO;
        } else {
            pendingHelp.hidden = YES;
            buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"warranty_claimed"];
        }
        [warrantyButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [warrantyButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [warrantyButton removeTarget:nil action:NULL forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];
        [warrantyButton setHidden:YES];
    } 
    else 
    {
       pendingHelp.hidden = YES;

       [warrantyButton setTag:claim.ID];
       UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"add_warranty"];
       [warrantyButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       [warrantyButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
       [warrantyButton addTarget:self action:@selector(haha:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
       warrantyButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
       warrantyButton.enabled = YES;
       [warrantyButton setHidden:NO];

    }
```

Might be it never goes into else part for assigning target. I hope you understand it better.

Comment: Tried that. It does go to the addTarget line when using Breakpoints. The weird thing is that it does setBackgroundImage properly, but the no buttons on the cell are clickable (I've used userInteractionEnabled as well)

Comment: Is it coming in else part but not going into  if(false){}else{} for adding target. So until unless u don't assign any target then how could it clickable. Please try my updated code

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're trying to replicate what the Sensible TableView framework already does. I'd recommend you check it out first.